# datatables use select-checkbox to get selected id and post via ajax easier way

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

How can I use datatables select-checkbox? The code below is for clicking table rows to get selected rows, but i want to do with datatables select checkbox and than post the values by ajax.

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var selected = [];

    $("#example").DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "scripts/ids-arrays.php",
        "rowCallback": function( row, data ) {
            if ( $.inArray(data.DT_RowId, selected) !== -1 ) {
                $(row).addClass('selected');
            }
        }
    });

    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var id = this.id;
        var index = $.inArray(id, selected);

        if ( index === -1 ) {
            selected.push( id );
        } else {
            selected.splice( index, 1 );
        }

        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    } );
} );
```

html:

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id </th>
      <th>First name</th>
      <th>Last name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>  
</table>
```

Comment: Which part are you having problems with?

Comment: Just trying to  integrate and use the select-checkbox

Comment: I think this question is too broad, you may need to break it down into smaller problems. This should get you started with displaying a checkbox column [www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/)